# Ldap starting stops after message

Tags: ldap

I am trying to start slapd.
When I enter following command:

```
/usr2/dap/libexec/slapd \
   -f /usr2/dap/etc/openldap/slapd.conf \
   -h "ldap://localhost:9011" \
   -l local4 \
   -d 256 \
```

I get the message "slapd starting."
It stops after this command.
I am not sure if my sldap is started and running or not.
Please help me with this.

```
500e8937 slapd starting
500e8937 daemon: added 5r listener=0
500e8937 daemon: added 7r listener=82f0cb8
500e8937 daemon: select: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
500e8937 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
500e8937 daemon: waked
500e8937 daemon: select: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
```

It stops here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ldapsearch` command line tool to determine if the server is running. For example, using the legacy OpenLDAP command line tool:

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -H ldap://localhost:9011 -b "" -s base "(&)" +
```

This command will retrieve operational attributes from the [root DSE](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html).

Edit: added `-xLLL` for simple LDIF output and force simple BIND instead of the default SASL.

Comment: It give this on ldapsearch command but I have give it in  different terminal                                                 SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started 
Please enter your password:

Comment: Thanks lot ,I put -X extra in above command                         One more query,IS It fine if Ldap is stopped at " 500e8937 daemon: select: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL " ,in above problem log

Comment: @ilyas If ldapsearch printed a result, OpenLDAP must be running, otherwise it isn't.